# Can I use a definition list to present trek information such as distance and ascent?

Tags: html

I have a series of information to display based on a walks distance, ascent etc. I could just do what I always do and use `div`'s, but I wanted to see if there is a more Semantic way to markup this information. Would it be more relevant to a `dl`?

I want to try

Here is the data from the design:
[image: Trek information from design]

Here is how my markup currently works:

```
<div class="contain mission-data--wrap">
    <div class="mission__line"></div>
    <div class="mission__data--distance">
        <p>Distance <span>17km/10.5 miles</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="mission__data--time">
        <p>Time <span>7 - 9 Hours</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="mission__date--accent">
        <p>Ascent <span>1352M</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="mission__data--gridref">
        <p>Grid Ref <span>NN123731</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this valid:

```
<dl class="contain mission-data--wrap">
    <dt class="mission__data--distance">Distance</dt>
    <dd>17km/10.5 miles</dd>

    <dt class="mission__data--time">Time</dt>
    <dd>7 - 9 Hours</dd>

    <dt class="mission__date--accent">Ascent</dt>
    <dd>1352M</dd>

    <dt class="mission__data--gridref">Grid Ref</dt>
    <dd>NN123731</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to HTML5 recommendations, it's perfectly legal to represent key-value pairs using `<dl>`s.

Citation from [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/dl.html#dl-details):

> The **dl** element represents a description list, which consists of zero or more term-description (**name-value**) groupings; each grouping associates one or more terms/**names** (the contents of dt elements) with one or more descriptions/**values** (the contents of dd elements).

Citation from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl#Metadata):

> Description lists are useful for displaying metadata as a list of key-value pairs.
>
> ```
> <dl>
>    <dt>Name</dt>    
>    <dd>Godzilla</dd>
>    <dt>Born</dt>
>    <dd>1952</dd>
>    <dt>Birthplace</dt>
>    <dd>Japan</dd>
>    <dt>Color</dt>
>    <dd>Green</dd>
> </dl>
> ```

IMO, a `dl` is far more appropriate for groups of key-value pairs (as in your case) than nested `div`s/`span`s.

Comment: For the sake of layout, would it be bad, in your opinion to split those 4 into seperate ```dl```? Only thinking this due to making my life when it comes to styling!

Comment: If all the metadata (all key-value pairs) refer to the same entity (the same trek in your case), and the keys are somehow related to each other, then it's semantically bad to split them into different `dl`s. But you may use `spans` inside `dt`s and `dd`s, as well as `class` attributes on `dt`s/`dd`s for styling purposes.